# How can I pass query string variables with NavigationService.Navigate?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Greetings,

Searched for this, but no luck.

I'm attempting to pass query string variables (and then retrieve them) in my Silverlight 4 app. First I tried this

```
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/LoanProductionRegion?Elvis=Alive&ImHungry=true", UriKind.Relative));
```

But HtmlPage.Document.QueryString doesn't pick them up because they come after the anchor (the full url looks like http://localhost:1076/Dashboard.SLTestPage.aspx#/LoanProductionRegion?Elvis=Alive&ImHungry=true).

I tried to put the vars in front, such as

```
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("?Elvis=Alive&ImHungry=true/LoanProductionRegion", UriKind.Relative));
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/?Elvis=Alive&ImHungry=true/LoanProductionRegion", UriKind.Relative));
```

But both result in a "Page not found" error. Anyone know how to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Have you checked this out...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/2009/04/28/silverlight-navigation-part-3.aspx

Comment: @Aaron: Not previously, no. Thanks. Seems pretty heavy duty for what should be a simple thing, though. Looking at that blog gave me an idea though. It's hacky, but I can get the Uri out of the NavigationEventArgs in the OnNavigatedTo method and parse myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OnNavigatedTo method in your page, and then inspect this.NavigationContext.QueryString["Elvis"] (or whatever other parameter name you like).

NavigationContext (much like NavigationService) is guaranteed to be initialized by the time OnNavigatedTo is called, so that's the most convenient time to inspect it in most cases.

NavigationContext.QueryString is simply an IDictionary that has pre-parsed the key-value pairs in the query string.  As such, you can do anything you expect with an IDictionary - use ContainsKey to see if something is present, iterate over it in a foreach loop, etc.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. No need to parse myself.