# Passing data between pages wp7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

I have a little question.
I have a data template like that :

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DangersItemTemplate">
        <Grid Height="102" Width="447" Tap="Grid_Tap">
            <Image Name="image" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="90" />
            <TextBlock Name="text" Text="{Binding Nom}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="102,16,16,22"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I want to use the Textlock control in the CSharp code to pass the Text property to the second xaml page, but I can't find the name of the control, it's inaccessible.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I just use VB.Net but I am sure you can convert.
Just use any shared variable in the application.
Here you can see it in an SourceCode example:

http://www.activevb.de/rubriken/kolumne/kol_30/res/nachtscanner.zip

Just use `Public Shared MyText As String` 
in Application Class. This vairable you can access anywhere. 
You can also use [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for that shared property to bind.

Alternatively you can use Navigation Query. Read more here:

[How can I pass query string variables with NavigationService.Navigate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555985/how-can-i-pass-query-string-variables-with-navigationservice-navigate)

Answer (score 0):

Your binding the Text of the TextBlock so you must have the value in your datacontext. I'd add this value to the Querystirng and navigate to the page.

```
var text = ((Whatever) DataContext).Nom;
string page2Uri = string.Foramt("/PAge2.xaml?Nom={0}", text);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(page2Uri, UriKind.Relative));
```

And then to get the data out of the querystring you can use the OnNavigatedTo method in your page, and then inspect this.NavigationContext.QueryString["nom"]

Or have a look into something like the MVVM pattern.